# How to read HeartRate from Samsung Health android SDK

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy-gear

I was trying long time ago but nothing works please I need help to read the steps and Heart Rate I want make them in one class put it's really hard :

https://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/health/index.html?com/samsung/android/sdk/healthdata/HealthConnectionErrorResult.html

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.smaunghealth">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read"
                   android:value="com.samsung.health.step_count;com.samsung.health.heart_rate"/>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Step Reporter : --> works successfully

```
public class StepCountReporter {

    private final HealthDataStore mStore;
    private StepCountObserver mStepCountObserver;
    private static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;

    public StepCountReporter(HealthDataStore store) {
        mStore = store;
    }

    public void start(StepCountObserver listener) {
        mStepCountObserver = listener;
        // Register an observer to listen changes of step count and get today step count
        HealthDataObserver.addObserver(mStore, HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, mObserver);
        readTodayStepCount();
    }

    // Read the today's step count on demand
    private void readTodayStepCount() {
        HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

        // Set time range from start time of today to the current time
        long startTime = getStartTimeOfToday();
        long endTime = startTime + ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;

        HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new ReadRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataType(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE)
                    .setProperties(new String[] {HealthConstants.StepCount.COUNT})
                    .setLocalTimeRange(HealthConstants.StepCount.START_TIME, HealthConstants.StepCount.TIME_OFFSET,
                            startTime, endTime)
                    .build();

        try {
            resolver.read(request).setResultListener(mListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Getting step count fails.", e);
        }
    }

    private long getStartTimeOfToday() {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return today.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<ReadResult> mListener = result -> {
        int count = 0;

        try {
            for (HealthData data : result) {
                count += data.getInt(HealthConstants.StepCount.COUNT);
            }
        } finally {
            result.close();
        }

        if (mStepCountObserver != null) {
            mStepCountObserver.onChanged(count);
        }
    };

    private final HealthDataObserver mObserver = new HealthDataObserver(null) {

        // Update the step count when a change event is received
        @Override
        public void onChange(String dataTypeName) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Observer receives a data changed event");
            readTodayStepCount();
        }
    };

    public interface StepCountObserver {
        void onChanged(int count);
    }
}
```

HeartRate : --> throw exception and not working

```
public class HeartRateReporter {

    private final HealthDataStore mStore;
    private HeartRateObserver mHeartRateObserver;
    private static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;

    public HeartRateReporter(HealthDataStore store) {
        mStore = store;
    }

    public void start(HeartRateObserver listener) {
        mHeartRateObserver = listener;
        HealthDataObserver.addObserver(mStore, HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE, mObserver);
        readHeartRate();
    }

    private void readHeartRate() {
        HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

        // Set time range from start time of today to the current time
        long startTime = getStartTimeOfToday();
        long endTime = startTime + ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;

        HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest.Builder()
                .setDataType(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE)
                .setProperties(new String[] {HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE})
                .setLocalTimeRange(HealthConstants.HeartRate.START_TIME, HealthConstants.HeartRate.TIME_OFFSET,
                        startTime, endTime)
                .build();

        try {
            resolver.read(request).setResultListener(mListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("*&*&*&", "Getting Heart fails.", e);
        }
    }

    private long getStartTimeOfToday() {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return today.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthDataResolver.ReadResult> mListener = result -> {
        int count = 0;

        try {
            for (HealthData data : result) {
                count += data.getInt(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE);
            }
        } finally {
            result.close();
        }

        if (mHeartRateObserver != null) {
            mHeartRateObserver.onChanged(count);
        }
    };

    private final HealthDataObserver mObserver = new HealthDataObserver(null) {

        @Override
        public void onChange(String dataTypeName) {
            Log.d("*&*&*&", "Observer receives a data changed event");
            readHeartRate();
        }
    };

    public interface HeartRateObserver {
        void onChanged(int count);
    }
}
```

Main Activity :

```
package com.example.smaunghealth;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String APP_TAG = "SimpleHealth";

    private static Main3Activity mInstance = null;
    private HealthDataStore mStore;
    private HealthConnectionErrorResult mConnError;
    private Set<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey> mKeySet;
    private StepCountReporter mReporter;
    private HeartRateReporter mHeartReporter;

    TextView stepCount ;
    TextView heartRate ;


    private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult> mPermissionListener =
            new HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult result) {
                    Log.d(APP_TAG, "Permission callback is received.");
                    Map<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey, Boolean> resultMap = result.getResultMap();

                    if (resultMap.containsValue(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                        // Requesting permission fails
                    } else {
                        // Get the current step count and display it
                    }
                }
            };


    private final HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener mConnectionListener = new HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is connected.");
            HealthPermissionManager pmsManager = new HealthPermissionManager(mStore);


            try {
                // Check whether the permissions that this application needs are acquired
                Map<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey, Boolean> resultMap = pmsManager.isPermissionAcquired(mKeySet);

                if (resultMap.containsValue(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                    // Request the permission for reading step counts if it is not acquired
                    pmsManager.requestPermissions(mKeySet, Main3Activity.this).setResultListener(mPermissionListener);
                } else {
                    // Get the current step count and display it
                    // ...

                    mReporter = new StepCountReporter(mStore);
                    mReporter.start(mStepCountObserver);

                    mHeartReporter = new HeartRateReporter(mStore);
                    mHeartReporter.start(heartRateObserver);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(APP_TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getMessage());
                Log.e(APP_TAG, "Permission setting fails.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(HealthConnectionErrorResult error) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is not available.");
            showConnectionFailureDialog(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is disconnected.");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInstance = this;

        stepCount= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.step_count);
        heartRate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heart_rate);

        mKeySet = new HashSet<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey>();
        mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));
        mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));

        HealthDataService healthDataService = new HealthDataService();
        try {
            healthDataService.initialize(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}

        mStore = new HealthDataStore(this, mConnectionListener);
        // Request the connection to the health data store
        mStore.connectService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mStore.disconnectService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private StepCountReporter.StepCountObserver mStepCountObserver = count -> {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Step reported : " + count);
        updateStepCountView(String.valueOf(count));
    };

    private HeartRateReporter.HeartRateObserver  heartRateObserver = count -> {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Step reported : " + count);
        updateHeartRateView(String.valueOf(count));
    };

    private void updateHeartRateView(String valueOf) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "heart rate reported : " + valueOf);
        updateHeartRateView(String.valueOf(valueOf));
    }

    private void updateStepCountView(String count) {
        stepCount.setText(count);

    }

    private void showConnectionFailureDialog(HealthConnectionErrorResult error) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mConnError = error;
        String message = "Connection with Samsung Health is not available";

        if (mConnError.hasResolution()) {
            switch(error.getErrorCode()) {
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.PLATFORM_NOT_INSTALLED:
                    message = "Please install Samsung Health";
                    break;
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.OLD_VERSION_PLATFORM:
                    message = "Please upgrade Samsung Health";
                    break;
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.PLATFORM_DISABLED:
                    message = "Please enable Samsung Health";
                    break;
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.USER_AGREEMENT_NEEDED:
                    message = "Please agree with Samsung Health policy";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "Please make Samsung Health available";
                    break;
            }
        }

        alert.setMessage(message);

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                if (mConnError.hasResolution()) {
                    mConnError.resolve(mInstance);
                }
            }
        });

        if (error.hasResolution()) {
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        }

        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Exception : [image]

Answer (score 1):

hiii... Munreeh  I just read your question I found an perfect solution for it you just need to pass start and end time for get heart rate

```
private void readHeartRate(long startTime, long endTime) {
        HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

        // Set time range to all day yesterday
        HealthDataResolver.Filter filter = HealthDataResolver.Filter.and(HealthDataResolver.Filter.greaterThanEquals(HealthConstants.HeartRate.START_TIME, startTime),
                HealthDataResolver.Filter.lessThanEquals(HealthConstants.HeartRate.START_TIME, endTime));
        HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest.Builder()
                .setDataType(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE)
                .setProperties(new String[]{
                        HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_BEAT_COUNT,
                        HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE
                })
                .setFilter(filter)
                .build();

        try {
            resolver.read(request).setResultListener(new HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthDataResolver.ReadResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(HealthDataResolver.ReadResult result) {
                    Log.w(APP_TAG, "Getting heart rate...");

                    int heartBeatCount;
                    long heartRate;
                    Cursor c = null;

                    try {
                        c = result.getResultCursor();
                        if (c != null) {
                            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                                Log.d(APP_TAG, "No heart rate entry found.");
                            }
                            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                                heartBeatCount = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_BEAT_COUNT));
                                heartRate = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE));
                                //Toast.makeText(context,""+heartRate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                mBeatcount.setText(""+heartRate);
                                Log.w(APP_TAG, "Heart beat count " + heartBeatCount
                                        + ", heart rate " + heartRate + "bpm"
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.close();
                        }
                    }

                    // TODO: Save heart rate to DB
                    //mCountDownLatch.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Getting heart rate failed.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to run read code in backgroud thread or work manager..  getting error Thread has no looper error

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 HealthDataObserver.addObserver(mStore, HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE, mObserver);
```

with

```
 HealthDataObserver.addObserver(mStore, HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, mObserver);
```

In HeartRateReporter